# Responsive layout using inline:block and variable width

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, lightbox, fluid-layout

I am modifying a lightbox (Magnific Popup) layout to include a reponsive caption div. The aim is to have the caption float next to the photo, and then collapse beneath the photo when the window is resized.

I want the caption to have a minimum width of about 300px (the exact width is not important, this can be a percentage). If the window width cannot accommodate the combined width of the photo (which varies from photo to photo) + the width of the caption, the caption should flow beneath the photo and span the full width of the photo, as you can see in this diagram -

[image]

The problem is this:

I have tried to use `display:inline-block` on both divs but cannot get the caption div to resize after it collapses underneath the photo. Can this be done in CSS? I know this is possible with media queries, however in this particular case it will be hard to determine an exact breakpoint because each photo has a different width.

Very much appreciate any help or advice you may have. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be easiest done with media queries. Set an arbitrary width, and have the caption float on the right when the window is wider, and make it 100% width when below. I.e:

```
/* Without media query */
.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
    ...
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .caption {
        position: static;
        width: 100%;
        ...
    }
}
```

I've illustrated this in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eczYP/.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a more 'fluid' solution (not based on max-width, since the photo size varies), but seems like this would be the best solution!

Comment: Yeah, in my experience, media queries is most often the most reasonable alternative when there is some fundamental change in behavior when screen width decreases.